# How to extract words from space in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a sentence in a column filename such as:

```
filename
Exact filename from California Dec 2015
Exact filename from Austin Jan 2015
```

I want to only extract date part from it like my expected output is:

```
filename
Dec 2015
Jan 2015
```

However I searched in Stackoverflow but I found two result but they didnot worked for me.

```
select regexp_substr(regexp_replace(filename
                                   ,'[[:space:]]-[[:space:]]'
                                   ,chr(11))
                    ,'([^'||chr(11)||']*)('||chr(11)||'|$)'
                    ,1 -- Start here
                    ,4 -- return 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. match
                    ,null
                    ,1 -- return 1st sub exp
                    )
```

Another method I tried is:

```
regexp_like(filename,'(^[:space:]|[:space:]$)');
```

However these both solution didnot worked for me.I searched more on SO but didnt got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the last two "words" in your column values, you can use this:

```
select regexp_substr(filename, '[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]][^[:space:]]+$') from table;
```

This expression matches: (anything except space)(space)(anything except space)(end)

Note that this only allows for one whitespace character between the last two words though.

Comment: can you help me to modify your answer Exact filename from California Dec 2015 (1).txt? if i have such filename

Comment: @DikshitKarki Then we will need to go with a different approach. Is it guaranteed that there will always be a 3-character month followed by 4-digit year? We can look for that instead of words.

Comment: there is variation of date some month are 6character.So, I am trying to understand the way you have solved. Please clarify me where i am doing mistake.At first (anything except space): It will go to Exact. (space) (anything except space).It will go upto filename (end) . I didnot understand how the (anything except space)(space)(anything except space)(end) is working? Please can u explain it so that I can resolve it myself

Comment: You're looking at the text from its start, which is incorrect. The first `(anything with space)` matches `Jan` (or `Dec`), not `Exact`.

Comment: CCC_East Emplozer Censxs Report May 2016 (1).txt201608  Your code is working for all kind of files except this one. Please help me to extract May 2016 from this column.Thank you.

Comment: How about: `regexp_substr(col, '(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[[:space:]][[:digit:]]{4}($|[[:space:]])')` ? This pattern matches  `(short month name)(space)(4-digit year)(end or space)`. But will fail if your month is 6-character as you commented earlier. We will need to look at your full data to come up with a fail-proof pattern.